# Accessing object which was created in different module

Tags: python

I am struggling to access the function of an object. To elaborate:
In my main python file I imported a class "objectA" from the module "simulation" and created the object.
Now I need to use another function stored in a separate module, which needs to call a function of this object.

```
# This is in my main file

from src.simulation import objectA
from src.testing import do_something

# creating the object
ObjA=objectA(param1=5, param2=10, param3=15)

# doing something
do_something()
```

...

```
# now in the file "testing.py"

def do_something():
    return ObjA.some_function()
```

...

now I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'ObjA' is not defined
```

How can I access the functions of the object without creating the object again?

Comment: Where are your imports in testing.py module ?

Comment: there are no imports in that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply: pass it as an argument.

```
def do_something(obj):
    return obj.some_function()


# creating the object
ObjA=objectA(param1=5, param2=10, param3=15)

# doing something
do_something(ObjA)
```

As a general rule: passing arguments and returning values (instead of relying on global variables - which, in Python, are only 'module-global' anyway - and/or mutating globals or arguments) is the simplest, most readable, most maintainable solution.

Also, this has absolutely nothing to do with OOP.

Oh and yes: [Python naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) are `all_lower` for variables, functions and modules and `CamelCase` for classes.

Comment: Also might be useful if inside 'do_something' function , has a verification if 'obj' has indeed that certain function, maybe something like: `if getattr(obj,'some_function') and callable(obj.some_function)`

Comment: @dejdej and what if the object doesn't have this attribute, or the attribute is not callable ? raise an `AttributeError` or a `TypeError` ? Those kind of checks can make sense when your function is designed to accept a whole range of types or interfaces and do different things based on type / capacities (debatable design but sometimes still the best practical solution), but most often your functions expects one single specific type or interface, and then those checks are mostly a waste of time since at this point you can't do much more than what the runtime WILL already do: raise an exception.

Answer (score 1):

instead of this

```
def do_something():
     return ObjA.some_function()
```

you can pass the object to function as a parameter and use like this

```
def do_something(ObjA):
     return ObjA.some_function()
```